# What does the "ss -s" result "Total:" value represent? How to get details on each of them?

Tags: proc, socket, sar

I am trying to understand what the `ss -s` result line `Total:` value represents, along with how this number is related to the other numbers.

Note, the following values are equivalent:

`ss -s Total:` == `sar's totsck` == `/proc/net/sockstat's sockets: used`

In the example below, it is my understanding the number `395` represents the number of sockets allocated, but not yet released.  What is the relationship between the `395` and the rest of the numbers listed?

How can I get an enumerations of what socket allocations make up the `395`, along with any/all information -- `socket port, time/age of socket allocation, application responsible`, etc.. for each them?

```
[root@server]# ss -s
Total: 395 (kernel 459)
TCP:   168 (estab 72, closed 60, orphaned 0, synrecv 0, timewait 60/0), ports 75

Transport Total     IP        IPv6
*         459       -         -
RAW       1         1         0
UDP       20        10        10
TCP       108       24        84
INET      129       35        94
FRAG      0         0         0
```

Comment: `ss` parse the `/proc/net/sockstat` to get the `Total` value. You must digg into the kernel code to know how it constructed.

Comment: Related kernal code:  sock_alloc increments the counter value, sock_release decrements it. But I need a way to enumerate what makes up the "Total:" value.  Notice the references to the sockets_in_use [ smp_processor_id() ].counter ++ / --
afinet_get_info: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/ipv4/proc.c?v=2.4.37#L64, socket_get_info: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/socket.c?v=2.4.37#L1734, sock_alloc: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/socket.c?v=2.4.37#L434, sock_release: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/socket.c?v=2.4.37#L475